# How Do I Fix TestFlight Crash "EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, crash, testflight

I am building this app and recently switched the app from React-Native to Expo and I have the app working fine on a simulator and with Expo GO with no logs for errors. When I go to upload the code to be deployed in the App Store Connect and try to open the app using TestFlight the app crashes as soon as it's opened. I've tried updating all of the dependencies, rebuilding the app and re-uploading it, changing dependencies, rewriting the podfile and redownloading the pods and anything else that I can think of or have found online, if you name it, I've most likely tried it. I just dont understand why this is happening if my code works perfectly in Expo GO. Here is the exact crash log that I get:
Incident Identifier: CCCEE621-763D-464A-B9B0-6F1743DBCE02
Hardware Model:      iPhone15,2
Process:             gwtexpo [11109]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B917015-F4C5-459B-BCD1-0899F3164A51/gwtexpo.app/gwtexpo
Identifier:          com.g.app
Version:             4.0.0 (1)
AppStoreTools:       15C5500a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone15,2:17
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.g.app [1937]

Date/Time:           2024-02-09 20:38:02.3026 -0500
Launch Time:         2024-02-09 20:38:01.7283 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.2.1 (21C66)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.20.06
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: gwtexpo [11109]

Triggered by Thread:  2

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x19c53669c __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:249)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1947cbc80 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x19c5bb334 -[NSException raise] + 16 (NSException.m:129)
3   gwtexpo                         0x104b1cb88 StartupProcedure.throwException(*:) + 16 (StartupProcedure.swift:350)
4   gwtexpo                         0x104b1cb88 protocol witness for ErrorRecoveryDelegate.throwException(*:) in conformance StartupProcedure + 16 (:349)
5   gwtexpo                         0x104b1cb88 ErrorRecovery.crash() + 2572 (ErrorRecovery.swift:281)
6   gwtexpo                         0x104b1b944 ErrorRecovery.runNextTask() + 824 (ErrorRecovery.swift:194)
7   gwtexpo                         0x104b1cf2c closure #1 in closure #1 in ErrorRecovery.tryRelaunchFromCache() + 232 (ErrorRecovery.swift:237)
8   gwtexpo                         0x104aea718 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable () -> () + 28 (:0)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a443f6a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1530)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a4441300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:561)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a4448894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748 (queue.c:3885)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a44493c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380 (queue.c:3976)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a4454004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288 (queue.c:6913)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1a4453878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404 (queue.c:6507)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x20646f964 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2629)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x20646fa04 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba9178 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8f10 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8e28 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8c68 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47fb1c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47da14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47d478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   GraphicsServices                0x00000001df9fe4f8 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
8   UIKitCore                       0x000000019e8a162c -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3685)
9   UIKitCore                       0x000000019e8a0c68 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5270)
10  gwtexpo                         0x0000000104abb02c main + 80 (main.m:7)
11  dyld                            0x00000001bf1b6dcc start + 2240 (dyldMain.cpp:1269)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646f9fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3bb1fbc __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000206473680 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1681)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a44f9b90 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000020639dff8 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000020638df90 demangling_terminate_handler() + 348 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:77)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001947ceda4 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:496)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000020639d3bc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000020639d360 std::terminate() + 108 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4441314 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:564)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4448894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748 (queue.c:3885)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a44493c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380 (queue.c:3976)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4454004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288 (queue.c:6913)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4453878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404 (queue.c:6507)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646f964 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2629)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646fa04 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646f9fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646f9fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba9178 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8f10 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8e28 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8c68 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47fb1c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47da14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47d478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   Foundation                      0x000000019b41048c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
8   Foundation                      0x000000019b43d74c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
9   UIKitCore                       0x000000019e8034a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 420 (UIEventFetcher.m:1208)
10  Foundation                      0x000000019b493de0 **NSThread__start** + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002064704d4 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:904)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646fa10 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646f9fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646f9fc start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba9178 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8f10 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8e28 mach_msg_overwrite + 436 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba8c68 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47fb1c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2624)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47da14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3007)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000019c47d478 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 (CFRunLoop.c:3420)
7   gwtexpo                         0x0000000104cbb04c +[RCTCxxBridge runRunLoop] + 212 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:332)
8   Foundation                      0x000000019b493de0 **NSThread__start** + 732 (NSThread.m:991)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002064704d4 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:904)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646fa10 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba9b1c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646efd4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001ac67eecc std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lockstd::__1::mutex&) + 28 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
3   hermes                          0x00000001059a8108 hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::worker() + 316 (:-1)
4   hermes                          0x00000001059a7fa8 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v15006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_deletestd::__1::__thread_struct >, hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::Exec... + 44 (:-1)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002064704d4 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:904)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646fa10 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001e3ba9b1c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646efd4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1228 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001ac67eecc std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lockstd::__1::mutex&) + 28 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
3   hermes                          0x00000001059a8108 hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::worker() + 316 (:-1)
4   hermes                          0x00000001059a7fa8 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v15006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_deletestd::__1::__thread_struct >, hermes::vm::HadesGC::Executor::Exec... + 44 (:-1)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002064704d4 _pthread_start + 136 (pthread.c:904)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000020646fa10 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
x4: 0x00000002063a236f   x5: 0x000000016b45e810   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000000
x8: 0x30e35a0d1570bfb3   x9: 0x30e35a0c7e354fb3  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000016b45e340
x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x00000000001ff800  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016b45f000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
x20: 0x0000000000001603  x21: 0x000000016b45f0e0  x22: 0x0000000000000114  x23: 0x000000016b45f0e0
x24: 0x0000000281930568  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000282d27680
x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016b45e780   lr: 0x0000000206473680
sp: 0x000000016b45e760   pc: 0x00000001e3bb1fbc cpsr: 0x40001000
esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x104ab4000 -         0x1050e7fff gwtexpo arm64  <5fa1c3ce25903b4e910bcfdddda0d56b> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B917015-F4C5-459B-BCD1-0899F3164A51/gwtexpo.app/gwtexpo
0x105398000 -         0x1053a3fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <26d68e81199a300dbc1530ba4630a611> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x1057cc000 -         0x10585ffff crsqlite arm64   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B917015-F4C5-459B-BCD1-0899F3164A51/gwtexpo.app/Frameworks/crsqlite.framework/crsqlite
0x1058dc000 -         0x105aabfff hermes arm64  <7427aebd5d7d36f9818c377d759607f4> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3B917015-F4C5-459B-BCD1-0899F3164A51/gwtexpo.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework/hermes
0x1947a0000 -         0x1947edfe0 libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <98c1e5b8c56e3b9c9783b0fef8f999ee> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x19b3e4000 -         0x19bf43fff Foundation arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x19c44a000 -         0x19c976fff CoreFoundation arm64e   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x19e675000 -         0x1a014afff UIKitCore arm64e  <99ad2a319360369f9c0ba7a0af33e2e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1a443d000 -         0x1a4483fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1a4484000 -         0x1a4501ff3 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <6e5a7692c1e935adb20bc307991df11c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1ac66c000 -         0x1ac6f9fff libc++.1.dylib arm64e  <73e549cc6e803b729b091c02f990e794> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1bf1b1000 -         0x1bf238b5b dyld arm64e  <630c2209dfd73c72b0a9e856c560f123> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1df9fb000 -         0x1dfa03fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <7d6f670c0e4b32158b4e599ef1ab9ed2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1e3ba8000 -         0x1e3be0fef libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <55f2cc41248837bdbb95ea2ffd7611ae> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x206389000 -         0x2063a4fff libc++abi.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x20646e000 -         0x206479ff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF

And this is the package.json:
{
"name": "gwtexpo",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start --dev-client",
"android": "expo run:android",
"ios": "expo run:ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
"@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.3",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.0",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.5",
"@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.2.3",
"@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
"@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
"@sentry/react-native": "5.17.0",
"axios": "^1.2.1",
"eas-cli": "^7.1.3",
"expo": "^50.0.4",
"expo-dev-client": "~3.3.8",
"expo-file-system": "~16.0.6",
"expo-font": "^11.10.2",
"expo-media-library": "~15.9.1",
"expo-network": "~5.8.0",
"expo-notifications": "~0.27.6",
"expo-sqlite": "~13.2.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
"expo-updates": "~0.24.10",
"i18next": "^22.4.9",
"intl-pluralrules": "^1.3.1",
"languagedetect": "^2.0.0",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-i18next": "^12.1.4",
"react-native": "0.73.4",
"react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.8.10",
"react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
"react-native-filereader": "^1.0.6",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
"react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.12",
"react-native-image-picker": "^5.0.0",
"react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.2",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
"react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
"react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
"react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
"react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.2.1",
"react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
"react-native-webview": "13.6.4",
"react-redux": "^8.0.5",
"redux": "^4.2.0",
"redux-saga": "^1.2.1",
"reselect": "^4.1.7",
"shorthash": "^0.0.2",
"store": "^2.0.12",
"translate": "^1.4.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.23.3",
"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.23.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
"@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.3",
"babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
"esbuild-jest": "^0.5.0",
"eslint": "^7.32.0",
"jest": "^29.3.1",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
"node-sass": "^8.0.0",
"react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
},
"private": true
}

If you could help at all please let me know. I've tried everything I can try on this site and read all the documents I can find or watched all the videos. Thank you

Nothing fixed it. I don't know if I should just continue trying to reupload the app to see if it works or not but I need something that can fix this. If you know something please help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).